# ‘icount’ at (1) is not a variable

Tags: fortran

Here's a part of my fortran code after compiling gives me an error saying that 'icount at (1) is not a variable

Here goes my code:

```
  integer*4 iy1
  integer*2 id1,im1
  parameter (month=12,maxper=5,specmax=8)
  real conc(month,8,icount(8,month))
  integer smonth(12),icount(8,month)
  real per(maxper),rper(maxper)
  data smonth/12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11/
  data per/0.10,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.90/



 open(unit=1`,file='data_co.txt',status='old')
 open(unit=2,file='chennai_alldatatop10.txt',status='unknown',iostat=ierr)
 if(ierr.eq.0)close(2,status='delete')
 open(unit=2, file='chennai_alldatatop10.txt',status='unknown')

     inum=0
2    read(2,*,end=3)id1,im1,iy1,conc1
     icount(1,im1)=inum+1
     conc(im1,1,icount(1,im1))=conc1
     goto 2
3    continue


     end
```

Comment: I haven't written Fortran in years, but I don't the variable `icount` defined anywhere because you are using it.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: It's already defined in the declaration section at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your variable declarations at the top of your code, you switched the order:

```
real conc(month,8,icount(8,month))
integer smonth(12),icount(8,month)
```

You are using `icount` before you defined it, so your code should look like this:

```
integer smonth(12),icount(8,month)
real conc(month,8,icount(8,month))
```

But actually, this doesn't make any sense either, if `icount(8, month)` has not yet been initialized to a value.  So your code *should* look like this:

```
integer smonth(12), icount(8,month)
real conc(month, 8, some_scalar_value)
```